# Is the definition of the meter arbitrary?

Tags: units, history, si-units, metrology

From Wikipedia, the definition of the meter is

> The meter is defined as the distance traveled by light in a vacuum in 1/299792458 seconds.

Why is this number of seconds chosen? Is there a motivation for this choice?

Comment: Did you read the sentences that follow the one you are quoting? Or the section titled [*Distance travelled by light in a specified time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#Distance_travelled_by_light_in_a_specified_time)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178660/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243144/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170978/26969

Comment: This has been asked multiple times before on this site. Do your due diligence and search before you ask.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - I have found no question that is a duplicate of this one. There are other, related question such as [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92969/26969) - and one could reasonably deduce the answer to this question from the answer to that one. But the question posed here appears to be different. Specifically - the question about the "arbitrary" definition of the second, while related to the "arbitrary" definition of the meter, is clearly different. The fact that the answer is the same ("because we chose to define the speed of light") is irrelevant, I think.

Comment: Other related questions: [Why does the speed of light $c$ have the value it does?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56973/), [The origin of the value of speed of light in vacuum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56973), [What makes '$c$' $c$? And what if it was slightly different?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291316), [Why is the speed of light exactly $299,792.458\:\rm{m/s}$ and not faster or slower?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235302), [on anthropometric units](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127602), (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) [Why is the speed of light defined as 299792458 m/s?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9314), [What is so special about speed of light in vacuum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80365), [Why $c$ is $3 \times 10^8$ times faster than a $1\:\rm{m/sec}$ car?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188018), [Why do universal constants have the values they do?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144262), [Measuring the speed of light and defining the metre - absolute or relative?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1383), and their many `Linked` questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes - because one can pick any distance one wants, and call it a meter (originally, it was 1/40,000,000th of the circumference of Earth measured over the poles; then the distance between a pair of lines on a standard platinum rod, then...).

But no - it is specifically chosen to be that value because

a) we believe the speed of light to be an absolute constant in the universe
b) by defining distance in terms of speed of light (a constant) and time (something we can measure precisely) we no longer need to maintain two separate standards.

The number was chosen such that the speed of light (which was previously known to be *approximately* 299,792,458 m/s) will henceforth be *exactly* that number.

Much detail on this can be found in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92969/26969) and the associated answers. Note that that question asks the *converse* of this one - namely, "why does the speed of light have no uncertainty". This is the other half of that question.